# How can I replace a non-standard (20cm) bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, taps

The bathroom sink has a separate cold and hot tap, their centres are 20cm apart. I want to replace them with a mixer tap. However, the mixer taps I see have 18cm distance.
What are the options for building in a mixer tap without getting a new sink?

---

EDIT:
I can't include pictures as I have only recently joined this forum. Some further details:

- the current 20cm centered faucets have their own water spouts
- the sink has two holes, but
- when looking from below, in the middle a circle can be seen where the sink is thinner (I guess this can be opened to get e third central hole)
- a common water spout in the middle is the goal, either with one or two handles
- there is a flat surface between the current two faucets
- there is a tiled flat wall behind the sink, so theoretically the new faucet could be built into the wall, but I would prefer not to remove tiles.

Comment: Per the [faq], until you have the rep, you can upload photos to an outside site and we'll add them to your post for you.

Comment: You should be able to add pictures now if you think one would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your existing faucets had individual water spouts then you could replace with a double handle type unit. This type can accommodate a large range of faucet to faucet center spacing as the faucet and mixing spout are interconnected under the sink via interconnecting hoses. Here are dimensions for a sample unit showing the range.

[image]

Here is link to online distributor web page for that unit.

http://www.faucetdirect.com/danze-wel-rom-double-handle-roman-tub-faucet-from-the-wellington-collection/p1789798

Comment: This faucet is really made more for a tub application than for a sink.

Answer (score 5):

I see that it is hard to recommend a robust solution for you because of several missing pieces of data. Here is a summary of questions that really need to be answered -

1. Are your current 200mm centered faucets each with their own water spout?
2. Does your sink have two holes or three?
3. When you say "mixer valve" are you referring to a single handle
   faucet or one with two handles but with a common water spout?
4. Is the space where the faucets are located and in between them a
   nice flat surface on the back of the sink?

If you have a two hole setup then you may be faced with either replacing the sink or boring a third center hole in the sink. A faucet like that pictured below is a center hole mounted unit that requires a 1 3/8" to 1 1/2" hole. It comes with an optional deck plate that can be used to cover a previous 2 or 3 hole installation. *(You would have to check though if the deck plate with this one would cover over the your existing 200mm spaced holes).*

[image]

On-Line retailer link:

http://www.faucet.com/danze-d225525rb-ac0fw1-oil-rubbed-bronze-single-handle-centerset-bathroom-faucet-from-the-aerial-collection/f1072590

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answers and questions! I will upvote as soon as I'll have sufficient score. I've answered your questions adding new text to my original question.